# Can anyone tell me how I create this effect in Photoshop or Illustrator please?

Tags: photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

Can anyone tell me how I create this Linocut effect to a photo in Photoshop or Illustrator please?

[image: Batersea]

[image: London]
[image: Thames]

Comment: Please do not leave answers as comments.

Comment: Marky Mark, please [edit] your question to tell us what you've tried already and where you got stuck. Screenshots or images of your own attempts would be beneficial as well.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These aren't effects. They are illustrations.  Somebody drew them.

Comment: This is not that board. So some answers can be made. Besides that, it has some upvotes. It can be reopened.